# install4j 8 and notarization for mac not working

Tags: macos, install4j, notarize

We are struggling to get install4j 8 Mac notarization to work.

Using install4j Multi-Platform Edition 8.0.2 (build 8057) on Mac Catalina.

The "Notarize macOS media files" check box is schecked resulting in a configuration:

```
    ...
    <buildOptions verbose="true" notarize="true" />
  </install4j>
```

But when we run

```
mvn release -Pinstall4j
```

we get the following log indicating that the notorization process has not been applied:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Important: macOS media sets have to be notarized before distribution.
[INFO]   More information in the code signing help.
[INFO]
```

Following the instructions in the following document:
https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/install4j.pdf

"If you build on macOS, install4j can perform the entire notarization process for you.In the install4j
IDE, the Notarize macOS media files check box on the "Build" step has to be selected (only
visible on macOS). For command line builds, the --apple-id and --apple-id-password
command line parameters or the equivalent parameters of the Gradle, Maven and Ant plugins
have to be set"

Our apple ID and password has been set in the maven settings.xml file for the install4j propfile:

```
      ...
      <install4j.appleId>[our notarization apple ID]</install4j.appleId>
      <install4j.appleIdPassword>[corresponding password]</install4j.appleIdPassword>
    </properties>
  </profile>
```

Need help to find the cause why the notarization process is not being run.

And a last question: Does install4j do any stapling of the notarization ticket to the installation program?

Kind regards
Tamas

Answer (score 1):

The currently released install4j maven plugin (1.1.1) does not have the `appleId` and `appleIdPassword` parameters, although the master branch of

https://github.com/sonatype/install4j-support/tree/master/install4j-maven-plugin

already has them.

In 8.0.3, you will be able to define the Apple ID on the "General Settings->Code Signing" step in the project and also set the system property `-Dinstall4j.appleIdPassword=...` externally as long as the Maven plugin does not have an updated release. You can write to support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.

> And a last question: Does install4j do any stapling of the notarization ticket to 
>   the installation program?

Yes, stapling is performed by install4j.